# What's the relationship between physicsbody.dynamic and physicsbody.categorybitmask

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Recently I have found that some sprite nodes can't test the collision with others. After some days trying and googling finally I made them works as usual. I have realized that there seems to be some relations between the dynamic and category bit mask. My guess is that:

```
player.dynamic = false
enemy.dynamic = true

player.category = player
enemy.collision = player
```

In the conditions above, enemy can't test the collision with player, but I wanna to know more details, any help will be appreciated.

update:

In my game, I want some of the sprites fixed in the scene, whose dynamic should be set to false, but can be collided by the players or enemies. For example the ground, a tree, or some buildings. What should I do to deal with these properties correctly ?

Like

```
tree.dynamic = false
enemy.collision = tree //can't works
tree.collision = enemy //should I do this? Is there another way to do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-dynamic bodies don't collide. From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic):

> The dynamic property controls whether a volume-based body is affected
>   by gravity, friction, **collisions with other objects**, and forces or
>   impulses you directly apply to the object.

Comment: but when I set player.collision = enemy , the player sprite node can test the collision. Is the collision testing has any directions?